# SortDescription bind PropertyName to dictionary value, key'd against an enum?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary, collectionview

I have a dictionary in my viewmodel like so:

```
Dictionary<Column, string> Columns{...}
```

Column is an enum and the program should sort by the columns, I got this far:

```
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedColumns" Source="{Binding RowValues}">
                <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                    <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="{Binding Goes here? something, something DataContext.Columns[Column.FirstName]?}"/>
                </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what **exactly** you want to achieve? An example would be helpful. The `PropertyName` property should contain a public property name of your data items (items from `RowValues` collection).

Comment: As per my question I want to do something like PropertyName=DataContext.Columns[Column.FirstName]